# How can I specify custom folders for file-browsing in Metro Apps?

Tags: windows-8, dropbox, modern-ui

Whenever you use an Metro app and you want to import some files there is a little file browser. Like this: [image: http://i.imgur.com/PGfn3.png]

A lot of folders possible; however there is a folder that is very important: The personal **Dropbox**. How can I add this folder as a "favorite" in this view? Always browsing through the whole filesystem is slow in the Metro Interface. I realize I could make symlinks for all the typical Dropbox folders but that's simply annoying and there has to be another way (just like it's possible to "hack" the "Send To..." options for the context menu.

Comment: Create a new Library in the Windows Explorer and add Dropbox there. Does this work?

Comment: @magicandre1981 nope.

Answer (score 0):

To be pinned on Windows Store Apps File Picker there must be another Windows Store App that implements File Picker Contracts.

If you are a Developer you could change the [windows sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-app-extension-0cb95155) to redirect to your personal dropbox folder.

Aside from that I don't believe that you are able to pin anything there that doesn't implements these contracts